# slide image across and text up on load

Tags: jquery

Rather hard to explain, but I am trying to create a smart slide, just one slide. No other slides needed.

Basically we have a div say 600px wide by 150px high. With border 1px solid whatever color.

On page load, blank slide appears, and image slides in from right to left, and simultaneously text slides in bottom to top in right hand portion of the div.

The image and text dock in final position, and animation ends. So it appears as per fig 4. in my drawing.

I have no code, because I dont really know where to start to do this, just wondering if anyone knows of some script to do this and perhaps point me in the right direction without getting angry at me.

I dont want anyone to code this for me, just perhaps give me soem pointers as I am happy to fiddle away and come back later and ask more questions.

Please see image below.

Cheers[image]

Comment: This seems quite easy to achieve. Just tell me... is there more slides to come in view... more texts... or only one image and one text? Some auto-slide? buttons?

Comment: Hey roxon thanks for commenting. No just the one slide, one image within the slide and one text block.

Comment: Right away! :) I'll post soon my answer.

Comment: done! :) hope this one will be ok. Ask me if you want some upgrades! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Hrh7P/)

used: `.animate()` and `.delay()` to delay the appearance of the text box:

```
$(function() {

    $('.imgbox').animate({left:'18'}, 1200);
    $('.textbox').delay(500).animate({top:'18'}, 700);

});
```

Comment: Mate bloody perfect thats exceptional, and JUST what I need. Seriously appreciate that. I really do !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Terribly sorry, but I just couldn't resist coding this......

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ndnAD/)

Main key points are:

1. use overflow hidden
2. use a relatively positioned container with absolute positioned child containers
3. animate to left:0% for horizontal and top:0% for vertical
4. run their animations one after another with the same time value to ensure they both arive at their destinations at the same time.

and there you have it.

Comment: Hahhaha awesome also ! Sheesh you guys are bloody clever ! I already chose roXon's answer because well he was first and its only fair. But voted this up too as it is so sleek ! Thanks @Joseph

Comment: @422 no problem :) he should get credit; but on the contrary, thank you for the fun time I had building this. :D

Comment: Well I am seriously thankful to both of you for creating these, I really am. Whats more you have saved me so much head and heart ache trying to achieve the same, but I would have used 4 billion lines of irrelevant code.